# I have a program in oracle, I need to select a specific value from an input box. Can I make a script that auto-applies a certain value to it?

Tags: arrays, oracle, select, input

So I was asked to do some work for a company that uses a simple oracle program to register some consumer IDs in their databases. In there there's a selection input button where I need to select an item (the store it was registered in). It's honestly annoying to have to select the same store every single time since the search in this is awful.

Would it be possible for me to make a script that automatically selects the store I want? (not an autoclicker)

Comment: Its not very clear what you are looking for. Possibly provide some scenario/examples with sample data (if possible) and expected output.

Comment: If it were the same store every time, then you wouldn't need to select it from a list of values. You didn't say which tool was used to create that application; in Apex (just for example), you could set "quick pick" value(s). Or, you could set a default value for that item. Or set column's default value. Or write a database trigger which would auto-populate that column with desired value.